# Features extraction with VGG16 for clustering

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, sift, vgg-net

I am asking a lot but I am very stuck on this one...

I have this part of code I used to extract features with SIFT, and I am trying to adapdt it to extract features based on a VGG16 model.

No matter how hard I try, I can't get passed through and always rise errors.

So if anyone can help to get the features in a way to use it for a clustering afterwards.

Here is the code with SIFT :

```
# identification of key points and associated descriptors
import time, cv2
sift_keypoints = []
temps1=time.time()
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(500)

for image_num in range(len(list_photos)) :
    if image_num%100 == 0 : print(image_num)
    image = cv2.imread(path+list_photos[image_num],0) # convert in gray
    image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(7,7),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT) #apply gaussianblur filter
    # image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res = cv2.equalizeHist(image)   # equalize image histogram
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(res, None)
    sift_keypoints.append(des)

sift_keypoints_by_img = np.asarray(sift_keypoints)
sift_keypoints_all    = np.concatenate(sift_keypoints_by_img, axis=0)
```

And here is how I use it for my clustering :

```
from sklearn import cluster, metrics

# Determination number of clusters

k = int(round(np.sqrt(len(sift_keypoints_all)),0))
print("Nombre de clusters estimés : ", k)
print("Création de",k, "clusters de descripteurs ...")

# Clustering
kmeans = cluster.MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, init_size=3*k, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(sift_keypoints_all)
```

What should I do to be able to extract features with a VGG model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an example regarding feature extraction with VGG16 in the official Keras documentation [1].

Note the layers of a convolutional network are successive representations of varying dimensions of your picture. Depending the layer you choose as output, the results from clustering may be very different.

[1] https://keras.io/api/applications/

Comment: Thanks Javier for your answer.
I found this example and it's working when I am trying to predict one picture, but whenever I try to apply it on several pictures, it doesn't want to work as I was able to do it with SIFT...